# Difference between List, Tuple, Sequence, Sequential, Iterable, Array, etc. in Ceylon

Tags: collections, ceylon

Ceylon has several different concepts for things that might all be considered some kind of array: `List`, `Tuple`, `Sequence`, `Sequential`, `Iterable`, `Array`, `Collection`, `Category`, etc. What's is different about these these types and when should I use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best place to start to learn about these things at a basic level is the [Ceylon tour](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/tour/sequences/). And the place to learn about these things in depth is the [module API](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Iterable.type.html). It can also be helpful to look at the [source files for these](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/tree/master/language/src/ceylon/language).

Like all good modern programming languages, the first few interfaces are super abstract. They are built around one formal member and provide their functionality through a bunch of default and actual members. (In programming languages created before Java 8, you may have heard these called "traits" to distinguish them from traditional interfaces which have only formal members and no functionality.)

## Category

Let's start by talking about the interface [`Category`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Category.type.html). It represents types of which you can ask "does this collection contain this object", but you may not necessarily be able to get any of the members out of the collection. It's formal member is:

```
shared formal Boolean contains(Element element)
```

An example might be the set of all the factors of a large number—you can efficiently test if any integer is a factor, but not efficiently get all the factors.

## Iterable

A subtype of `Category` is the interface [`Iterable`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Iterable.type.html). It represents types from which you can get each element one at a time, but not necessarily index the elements. The elements may not have a well-defined order. The elements may not even exist yet but are generated on the fly. The collection may even be infinitely long! It's formal member is:

```
shared formal Iterator<Element> iterator()
```

An example would be a stream of characters like standard out. Another example would be a range of integers provided to a for loop, for which it is more memory efficient to generate the numbers one at a time.

This is a special type in Ceylon and can be abbreviated `{Element*}` or `{Element+}` depending on if the iterable might be empty or is definitely not empty, respectively.

## Collection

One of `Iterable`'s subtypes is the interface [`Collection`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Collection.type.html). It has one formal member:

```
shared formal Collection<Element> clone()
```

But that doesn't really matter. The important thing that defines a `Collection` is this line in the documentation:

> All `Collection`s are required to support a well-defined notion of value
>   equality, but the definition of equality depends upon the kind of
>   collection.

Basically, a `Collection` is a collection who structure is well-defined enough to be equatable to each other and clonable. This requirement for a well-defined structure means that this is the last of the super abstract interfaces, and the rest are going to look like more familiar collections.

## List

One of `Collection`'s subtypes is the interface [`List`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/List.type.html). It represents a collection whose elements we can get by index (`myList[42]`). Use this type when your function requires an array to get things out of, but doesn't care if it is mutable or immutable. It has a few formal methods, but the important one comes from its other supertype [`Correspondence`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Correspondence.type.html):

```
shared formal Item? get(Integer key)
```

## Sequential, Sequence, Empty

The most important of `List`'s subtypes is the interface [`Sequential`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Sequential.type.html). It represents an immutable `List`. Ceylon loves this type and builds a lot of syntax around it. It is known as `[Element*]` and `Element[]`. It has exactly two subtypes:

- `Empty` (aka `[]`), which represents empty collections
- `Sequence` (aka `[Element+]`), which represents nonempty collections.

Because the collections are immutable, there are lots of things you can do with them that you can't do with mutable collections. For one, numerous operations can fail with `null` on empty lists, like [`reduce`](http://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2013/12/23/reduce/) and `first`, but if you first [test that the type is `Sequence`](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.0/reference/operator/nonempty/) then you can guarantee these operations will always succeed because the collection can't become empty later (they're immutable after all).

## Tuple

A very special subtype of `Sequence` is [`Tuple`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Tuple.type.html), the first true class listed here. Unlike `Sequence`, where all the elements are constrained to one type `Element`, a `Tuple` has a type for each element. It gets special syntax in Ceylon, where `[String, Integer, String]` is an immutable list of exactly three elements with exactly those types in exactly that order.

## Array

Another subtype of `List` is [`Array`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/Array.type.html), also a true class. This is the familiar Java array, a mutable fixed-size list of elements.

Answer (score 4):

drhagen has already answered the first part of your question very well, so I’m just going to say a bit on the second part: when do you use which type?

In general: **when writing a function, make it accept the most general type that supports the operations you need.** So far, so obvious.

**`Category`** is very abstract and rarely useful.

**`Iterable`** should be used if you expect some stream of elements which you’re just going to iterate over (or use stream operations like `filter`, `map`, etc.).

Another thing to consider about `Iterable` is that it has some extra syntax sugar in named arguments:

```
void printAll({Anything*} things, String prefix = "") {
    for (thing in things) {
        print(prefix + (thing?.string else "<null>"));
    }
}

printAll { "a", "b", "c" };
printAll { prefix = "X"; "a", "b", "c" };
```

[Try online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=440b4b5fa5475ea26794)

Any parameter of type `Iterable` can be supplied as a list of comma-separated arguments at the end of a named argument list. That is,

```
printAll { "a", "b", "c" };
```

is equivalent to

```
printAll { things = { "a", "b", "c" }; };
```

This allows you to craft DSL-style expressions; the [tour](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/named-arguments/) has some nice examples.

**`Collection`** is, like `Correspondence`, fairly abstract and in my experience rarely used directly.

**`List`** sounds like it should be a often used type, but actually I don’t recall using it a lot. I’m not sure why. I seem to skip over it and declare my parameters as either `Iterable` or `Sequential`.

**`Sequential` and `Sequence`** are when you want an immutable, fixed-length list. It also has some syntax sugar: variadic methods like `void foo(String* bar)` are a shortcut for a `Sequential` or `Sequence` parameter. `Sequential` also allows you to do use the `nonempty` operator, which often works out nicely in combination with `first` and `rest`:

```
String commaSeparated(String[] strings) {
    if (nonempty strings) {
        value sb = StringBuilder();
        sb.append(strings.first); // known to exist
        for (string in strings.rest) { // skip the first one
            sb.append(", ").append(string);
            // we don’t need a separate boolean to track if we need the comma or not :)
        }
        return sb.string;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

[Try online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=1f37bb05573ba7633949)

I usually use `Sequential` and `Sequence` when I’m going to iterate over a stream several times (which could be expensive for a generic `Iterable`), though `List` might be the better interface for that.

**`Tuple`** should never be used as `Tuple` (except in the rare case where you’re abstracting over them), but with the `[X, Y, Z]` syntax sugar it’s often useful. You can often refine a `Sequential` member to a `Tuple` in a subclass, e. g. the superclass has a `<String|Integer>[] elements` which in one subclass is known to be a `[String, Integer] elements`.

**`Array`** I’ve never used as a parameter type, only rarely as a class to instantiate and use.

Comment: I don't understand how your `printAll` example can even work. You write that "Any parameter of type Iterable can be supplied as a list of comma-separated arguments at the end of a named argument list". But how can this be possible when calling `printAll`, seeing that the named argument `prefix ` comes AFTER the named argument `strings` in the function definition.

Comment: Well, `prefix` is optional, so you’re allowed to omit it. And a comma-separated argument list in a named argument list always applies to the first unassigned `Iterable` argument, which is `things`. The order of `things` and `prefix` doesn’t matter directly in this case (though it’s still not possible to swap the parameters for a different reason – you can’t have a required parameter (`things`) after an optional one (`prefix`)).

Comment: You use the concept 'a named argument list', but how does Ceylon know that we're dealing wth 'a named argument list' in this case: `printAll { "a", "b", "c" };`

Comment: Or do you refer to characteristics of function definitions when you talk about 'named argument lists'? Then my question will be almost the same:
How does Ceylon know that the argument list in the following function definition is particularly 'namish', compared to the argument lists of other function definitions?
`void printAll({Anything*} things, String prefix = "") {
    for (thing in things) {
        print(prefix + (thing?.string else "<null>"));
    }
}`

Comment: A named argument list is one enclosed in braces (`f { argument; }`), a positional argument list is one enclosed in parentheses (`f(argument)`). You can call any¹ function with either syntax, it’s up to you. (¹at least in pure Ceylon; interop with other languages can get finicky)